# restful json resource relation model

Tags: json, api, rest

I hope the title makes sense, anyway...

if my RESTful api has the following resources:

```
GET /hands
GET /hands/1
GET /hands/1/fingers
```

When the client GET's /hand or /hand/1 should the response Json contain an array of the child resource "fingers", an array of finger id's, or no array for fingers and the client must do a second GET request for /hands/1/fingers to consume that resource?

What is the most commonly accepted practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option is not RESTful since it would not allow the client to navigate to the `fingers` subresources. You must not force the client to know how the URLs to your resources are structured.

So this leaves you with

1. include the subrescource inline, or
2. link to them.

Note that the second options means link as in link: a complete link (absolute or relative) must be present for every finger. An ID is *not* enough since it forces the client to know what to do with it.

What option is better? This dependes on your scenario. Do you want to work with the fingers on their own? How big ist the representation of the the resources and subresources?

I'd go for option 1 unless I have a specific reason not to.